# NavigationDrawer and ViewPager - swiping issue

Tags: android, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have a `ViewPager` with 3 fragments in it. I have extended `ViewPager` and disabled its swiping abilities for reasons specific to my app. So, for navigation between these fragments, I've added a `TabLayout` to to my activity.

In my second fragment (the one "in the middle") I have a `DrawerLayout` on the left edge.
Everytime I make a swiping motion from left to right in that fragment, the `DawerLayout` is shown, **even if I swipe in the middle of the screen. It should only happen if I swiped close to the left edge of the screen.**

I've been having a hard time understanding touch and motion events handling in Android... Is there a way to keep my `ViewPager` (swiping disabled) and restrict the touch events `DrawerLayout` 'listens to' to the edge of the screen (as its supposed to)?

If I do not modify the `ViewPager` (that is, if I keep swiping enabled), it also does not work because swiping from the left edge will begin to open the `DrawerLayout`, but at the same time, will begin the `ViewPager`'s transition.

I've recreated the issue in a small app.

This is MyViewPager:

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Fragment Fragment1;
    Fragment Fragment2;
    Fragment Fragment3;
    MyViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Fragment1 = new Fragment1();
        Fragment2 = new Fragment2();
        Fragment3 = new Fragment3();

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.TabLayout);

        viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        if (Fragment1 == null) {
                            Fragment1 = new Fragment1();
                        }
                        return Fragment1;
                    case 1:
                        if (Fragment2 == null) {
                            Fragment2 = new Fragment2();
                        }
                        return Fragment2;
                    case 2:
                        if (Fragment3 == null) {
                            Fragment3 = new Fragment3();
                        }
                        return Fragment3;
                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            }


            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 3;
            }


            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return "frag1";
                    case 1:
                        return "frag2";
                    case 2:
                        return "frag3";
                    default:
                        return "0";
                }
            }
        });

        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

ActivityMain' layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4dea21">

    <com.example.android.navbarviewpager.MyViewPager
        android:id="@+id/ViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#ea3ee2"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/TabLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
        app:tabMode="scrollable">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="frag1"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="frag2"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="frag3"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment1:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    }
}
```

Fragment2:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);

    }
}
```

Fragment3:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3, container, false);

    }
}
```

Fragment TWO's layout (the one with the DrawerLayout):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#a2a2ee"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="fragmento DOIS"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:background="#b9b9b9"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notified_nav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TTTTT"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/overdue_nav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="XXXXX"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the other fragments' layouts:

Fragment ONE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frag_1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#eea2a2"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="fragmento UM"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment THREE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frag_1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#abeea2"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="fragmento TRÊS"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't think that it is possible to have a horizontal `ViewPager` AND a horizontal `DrawerLayout` on top of each other, you could turn either one by 90 degree and make it a vertically sliding view (easy in the case of the `DrawerLayout` and, if you use a library-there are a number on github, also easy in the case of the `ViewPager`).

Concerning what seems to be at the core of your question: it is possible to limit the sensitive area of a `DrawerLayout` to the edge it is sliding from. To do so, you need to override `DrawerLayout` and use it instead of `DrawerLayout` in `/layout/fragment2.xml`.

This is the code:

```
public class MyDrawerLayout extends DrawerLayout {
    Context context;

    public MyDrawerLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyDrawerLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        // if the drawer is open already, pass motionEvent upwards
        if (this.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
        // sensitive area is set to 1/4 of the drawer's full width
        // adopt to your needs
        int sensitiveWidth = ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout).getWidth() / 4;
        // if the drawer is not (fully) open AND
        // motionEvent.getX() is close to the left edge,
        // fully open the drawer and pass motionEvent upwards
        if (motionEvent.getX() < sensitiveWidth) {
            this.openDrawer(Gravity.START);
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }
        // otherwise eat motionEvent
        return false;
    }
}
```

Two notes:

1. Once the drawer is open, you probably want it to close after *any* interaction, even if it lies outside the "sensitive area". This is what the first *if*-clause in `onInterceptTouchEvent` is for.
2. While the drawer is not fully open, the implementation *swallows* `MotionEvent`s on the `DrawerLayout` outside of the "sensitive area". Therefore space for a "fling" gesture is narrow. In order to make opening the drawer easy, opening it programmatically is the option I am suggesting here. If your app does not rely on half opened/closed drawers, this seems like a good solution in terms of usability.

Comment: It worked out great, thank you. Is there a way to disable the 'peeking' state of the drawer (when there's just a little piece of it visible on the screen)? I've been looking through DrawerLayout's source code, but I don't know where to start (beginner here).

Comment: You could add something like `if (this.isDrawerVisible(Gravity.START) && !this.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START){// do something, for example, close drawer}` to the `onInterceptTouchEvent` method.

Comment: I see, it's visible but not open. It didn't work in `onInterceptTouchEvent`, but in a `SimpleDrawerListener` `onDrawerStateChanged` it did. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48131928/3117650) I explain how you can user a TabLayout to move in all for direction this can help.

And for your case you can user a gesture detector

```
gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(e1.getY() - e2.getY(), e2.getX() - e1.getX()));

        if (angle > -45 && angle <= 45) {
            if(goRight != 5) mainContainer.setCurrentItem(goRight);
            return true;
        }

        if (angle >= 135 && angle < 180 || angle < -135 && angle > -180) {
            if(goLeft != 5) mainContainer.setCurrentItem(goLeft);
            return true;
        }

        if (angle < -45 && angle >= -135) {
            if(goUp != 5)mainContainer.setCurrentItem(goUp);
            return true;
        }

        if (angle > 45 && angle <= 135) {
            if(goDown != 5)mainContainer.setCurrentItem(goDown);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


});
```

And this

```
someView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The important step is set your "**someView**" in your .xml as the area where you want get the movement. You don't need to watch the whole screen

Hope it helps