# Make Swap Vertical and Horizontal Work With Two Adapters

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, adapter

So basically I'm trying to make my app like snapchat where you can swipe left,right,up and down. My problem is that the app does not realize there are two adapters and only works one or the either(Vertically or Horrizontally).How do I make it so that I can swipe vertically as well as Horizontally on my

> EmptyFragment

I currently have my VerticalViewPagerAdapter extending to a FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public VerticalViewPager(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return SettingsFragment.create();
        case 1:
            return EmptyFragment.create();
        case 2:
            return ExtrasFragment.create();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

As well as my HorizontalViewPagerAdapter

```
public class HorizontalViewPager extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public HorizontalViewPager(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return ChatFragment.create();
            case 1:
                return EmptyFragment.create();
            case 2:
                return StoryFragment.create();
        }
        return null;
    }


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

And somehow I cant have them in sync its either one or the other and I can alter if my app goes vertical or horizontal by changing my layoutfile

```
<View
android:id="@+id/am_background_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/green"/>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/am_view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<me.kaelaela.verticalviewpager.VerticalViewPager
    android:id="@+id/am_scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Im not sure if it has to do with my MainActivity which is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //VerticalViewPager
    me.kaelaela.verticalviewpager.VerticalViewPager verticalViewPager = findViewById(R.id.am_scrollView);
    VerticalViewPager scrollViewAdapter = new VerticalViewPager(getSupportFragmentManager());
    verticalViewPager.setAdapter(scrollViewAdapter);
    verticalViewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new DefaultTransformer());

    //HorizontalViewPager
    View background = findViewById(R.id.am_background_view);
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.am_view_pager);
    HorizontalViewPager adapter = new HorizontalViewPager(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting the base from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48108078/3117650).

Create a **GestureDetectorCompat** object

```
GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat;
```

and override **onTouchEvent** in the activity

```
 @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
```

or if you want to detect on some view then you can Override **onTouch**

```
someView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

and initialize gestureDetectorCompat as follows somewhere preferably in **onCreate()** and you are done.

```
gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            float angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(e1.getY() - e2.getY(), e2.getX() - e1.getX()));

            if (angle > -45 && angle <= 45) {
                if(goRight != 5) mainContainer.setCurrentItem(goRight);
                return true;
            }

            if (angle >= 135 && angle < 180 || angle < -135 && angle > -180) {
                if(goLeft != 5) mainContainer.setCurrentItem(goLeft);
                return true;
            }

            if (angle < -45 && angle >= -135) {
                if(goUp != 5)mainContainer.setCurrentItem(goUp);
                return true;
            }

            if (angle > 45 && angle <= 135) {
                if(goDown != 5)mainContainer.setCurrentItem(goDown);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }


    });
```

Then you can use `mainContainer.setCurrentItem(number);` to go to other position/fragment.

Don't forget that the number change if you are in different number. Like this

```
switch(adapter.getCurrentItem()){
    case 0:
        goRight = 2;
        goLeft = 4;
        goUp = 3;
        goDown = 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        goRight = 5;
        goLeft = 5;
        goUp = 0;
        goDown = 5;
        break;
    case 2:
        goRight = 5;
        goLeft = 0;
        goUp = 5;
        goDown = 5;
        break;
    case 3:
        goRight = 5;
        goLeft = 5;
        goUp = 5;
        goDown = 0;
        break;
    case 4:
        goRight = 0;
        goLeft = 5;
        goUp = 5;
        goDown = 5;
        break;
}
```

When you are in the fragment 4 you can only go to 0, not 2 if you swipe left-right.

And this should be your adapter

```
public class SwipeViewPager extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public SwipeViewPager(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return EmptyFragment.create();
        case 1:
            return StoryFragment.create();
        case 2:
            return ExtrasFragment.create();
        case 3:
            return ChatFragment.create();
        case 4:
            return SettingsFragment.create();
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 5;
}
```

Comment: Just wondering the DEBUG_TAG is invalid what should I do about that?

Comment: This is only for show in your log what you are doing. You can put your on String like "Action of User" or you can even remove the whole line

Comment: Also do I put these codes in the mainActivity or in the baseFragment. Sorry kind of new to coding

Comment: you have to put here is you container, probably in MainActivity.
The "someView" is your container or the whole screen.

Comment: Im not sure how to use the container.

Comment: Put your viewPager variable. This is your container.